# SBT TaskKey If Statement

Tags: if-statement, sbt

I'm using SBT 0.13. I'm running into a problem, which is exhibited by the following toy example:

```
lazy val nativeOne = TaskKey[Unit]( "nativeOne", "One" )
lazy val nativeTwo = TaskKey[Unit]( "nativeTwo", "Two" )

lazy val testProj = Project(
    id = "testProj",
    base = file( "." ),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
        scalaVersion := "2.10.2",
        nativeOne :=
        {
            println( "Native one"
        },  
        nativeTwo :=
        {
            if ( true )
            {
                println( "Native two" )
            }
            else
            {
                val n1 = nativeOne.value
            }
        }
    )
)
```

If I go into sbt and run `nativeTwo`:

```
> nativeTwo
Native one
Native two
```

Why is this happening? Why is the `false` branch being evaluated? Is branching in TaskKeys not allowed?

Comment: I imagine this is happening because there is macro magic that spots (at compile time) the access of nativeOne.value and adds a task dependency. In the general case, the macro doesn't get to know which path of an if is evaluated - so it has to always add the dependency.

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: You can dynamically (at run-time) add nodes to the build graph. There's an incantation that uses Def.taskDyn. A tangentially related example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224898/idiomatically-defining-dynamic-tasks-in-sbt-0-13

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In sbt *ALL* dependencies are computed in parallel before your task runs.  If you were to construct a graph of what you have, it would be:

```
nativeOne
   ^
   |
nativeTwo
```

What you're trying to do is *order* the tasks.   In sbt, we try to promote tasks returning the results that other tasks use directly, hence the `.value`.  What that does is not directly run a task, but say "give me the result of this other task".

The best way understand sbt's syntax is as a mimic of the scala-async project.  Your code is similar to the following async code:

```
nativeOne = async {
  println( "Native one")
}
nativeTwo = async {
  if(true) println("Native Two")
  else await(nativeOne)
}
```

There, it's a little more obvious that you're just saying "wait for the value if it hasn't already computed.

If you want to optionally execute a Task, you need to do so at the `Task[_]` layer of sbt, which is a bit more verbose.  We're using a 'dynamic task'.  That is one that chooses which tasks are actually run at runtime.

SO, you'll need to use the `Def.taskDyn` method which lets you compose tasks in the order they are defined.  You'll work on the tasks themselves using the `toTask` method of `TaskKey`s.  This is instead of working on the *values* the tasks produce.  Here's an example `build.sbt`:

```
val taskOne = taskKey[Int]("test")

val taskTwo = taskKey[Int]("test2")

val taskThree = taskKey[Int]("test3")

val switchEm = settingKey[Boolean]("switch 'em")

switchEm := true

taskOne := { println("taskOne"); 1 }

taskTwo := { println("taskTwo"); 2 }

taskThree := Def.taskDyn({
  if(switchEm.value) taskTwo.toTask
  else taskOne.toTask
}).value
```

And then in the sbt console:

```
> reload
[info] Loading project definition from /home/jsuereth/projects/sbt/test-projects/project
[info] Set current project to test-projects (in build file:/home/jsuereth/projects/sbt/test-projects/)
> taskThree
2
```

Also note, you won't see the corrected dependencies in the inspect command, because the dependencies are *dynamically* added:

```
> inspect taskThree
[info] Task: Int
[info] Description:
[info]  test3
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/home/jsuereth/projects/sbt/test-projects/}test-projects/*:taskThree
[info] Defined at:
[info]  /home/jsuereth/projects/sbt/test-projects/build.sbt:15
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  *:switchEm
[info]  *:settingsData        <- TaskOne + TaskTwo are missing, this replaces
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:taskThree
[info]  {.}/*:taskThree
[info]  */*:taskThree
```