# Add SBT tasks dynamically

Tags: scala, sbt

Is is possible to create user specific tasks dynamically?

For example in my SBT plugin I will read some settings key (a `Seq[_]`) and for each element in that `Seq` I would generate a task on plugin initialization.

My idea is to expose user defined tasks like this:

```
myplugin:usertask1 <-- "usertask1" is registered automatically on load.
```

Is it possible somehow or am I missing something?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19224898/1553233) something similar to what you want to do?

Comment: @marios yes, it looks like what I want, but I'm not sure. The thing is, I will use this automatically loaded tasks in SBT directly (using autocompletion etc) like normal tasks. I will try this solution. Thanks.

Comment: Each of these task will need to have some code right? Where do you define their code?

Comment: @marios yes, each task have some code. This code will be provided by user of my plugin. There is a special sbt setting for that (Seq[_] of such tasks - like Runnables or Callables). I want to traverse this list and for each element create a new SBT task which will contain a call of that Runnable. Something like what.